# storing error code and messages in web.config

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, web

In my  ASp.NEt MVC Application We have "Error codes" and respective "Error messages" We thinking to store these in web.config as Key Value Pair, Keeping in mind if some changes to these elements will avoid recompilation of code. Is it a good way to store these in web.config or Is there any other way??

Answer (score 1):

better way is to make new resource project so you can have error as resources.
it has various benefits like in case of change you need to just change the resource project dll, second benefit is you can use resource file in localization in future if it is needed.

Comment: Completely agree with this.A better way indeed.

Answer (score 1):

> It's not good. because the the error message will change for different users and different situation  .

You can store it to Database

table have

Id- error code     - error message -

1  -   404            - page not found, Please redirect other page, it's under maintenance , etc..

> When your server side get the 404 error, you can show the error to the user on a error page 
>    and Also we can store the class and method name , which line , column  by using [StackTrace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.exception.stacktrace%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) . The StackTrace helps to understand the error details, which class and which line

That's one type

another way is

[Read this](http://ben.onfabrik.com/posts/aspnet-mvc-custom-error-pages)

Comment: I agree with this, you can add other columns to table like user_id, color and so on.

Comment: @JhoonBey Also we can store the  class and method name , which column get a error  and etc by using StackTrace . :+1:

Answer (score 0):

Since We cannot access web.config from javscript file, We have decided to keep the key, values in one of the java script file as **Associative array**. This was requied to do client side valdation. thanks for the inputs gieven